# How to communicate binary and string data between Java and Android over network?

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I'm trying to develop a server/client software which binary and string data should be transmitted over the internet from a Java server to an Android client and vise versa.
I've tried using Java and Android sockets but it's getting very complicated. 
Are there any alternative classes/libraries which can help me?

Comment: Could you explain why you got into complications  sending both string and binary data?

Comment: because the binary and string data could be transmitted simultaneously so here are the problems: 1.How to send and receive binary and string data at the same time (without blocking) 2.Handling that which binary data is related to which string data?

Comment: Sorry  i do not understand the problem. If you have two strings  you can send them one  by one.  If you have a string and some binary data then first send the string and then bthe binary data. Or reverse the sequence.

Comment: You cannot send things simultaneously if  you use only one  connection, one port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with RestFul services. They are supposed to be simple and supported on any platform which supports HTTP.. i.e. almost every platform out there. Unless you are looking for really high performance, I would recommend against sockets (suitable only for specialized scenarios, given several other choices of technologies today).